# Mounting an encrypted partition from a drive image

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, backup, mount, bitlocker

**BACKGROUND INFO:**

I have 2 drives.  1 drive has Windows 10 Pro and the other drive has Linux.  Both drives are encrypted.  The Windows drive is encrypted with BitLocker and the Linux drive is encrypted with Luks/lvm.

I backed up both drives using the following 2 commands:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/external-usb-drive/windows.img
dd if=/dev/sda of=/external-usb-drive/linux.img
```

I was then able to use the following commands to mount the encrypted partition and access the data I needed from the `linux.img` backup:

```
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop100 /external-usb-drive/linux.img 
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop100p5 linux_backup
cd /mnt
sudo mkdir linux_backup
sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt/linux_backup
```

I was then able to simply browse to the mount point using a file browser such as nautilus in Linux.

---

**THE QUESTION:**

I would like to test the `windows.img` backup too before I wipe the windows drive.

How do I mount and test the encrypted partition in the windows.img file from Windows 10 Pro?  Would be nice if I could simply browse to the mount location (once mounted) using the windows file explorer.

Comment: Start with `losetup -P` I guess. Feels like it will lead to nowhere though (access how?).

Comment: @TomYan, updated OP with background info.

Comment: Windows only do its vhd(x) files I think, and Linux won't do BitLocker.

Comment: In that case, what's the simpliest way for me to backup the entire windows drive so it can later be mounted again to retrieve data from the backup? vhd(x)?

Comment: Check out Disk2vhd. Hyper-V has a wizard for that as well IIRC.

Comment: You might try using checksums to verify the images - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45817/how-to-check-integrity-of-a-dd-backup . BTW, kudos for checking before use... I'd worked for a firm that made daily backups, but never verified 'em. On the day they were needed, none worked.

Comment: @TomYan, tried disk2vhd and used a hyper-v vm, but it's so clunky.  It does work though.  Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, thank you for suggesting checksums.

Answer (score 0):

Using a vhd(x) file and created a hyper-v vm worked but was extremely clunky.  I found the following solution to be better:

From an Ubuntu LiveCD/USB (untested using the Windows 10 Linux subsystem):

```
sudo apt install dislocker
sudo mkdir /media/bitlocker
sudo mkdir /media/mount
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop100 /external-usb-drive/windows.img 
sudo dislocker -v -V /dev/loop100p2 -u -- /media/bitlocker
sudo mount -o loop,rw /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Comment: For the record, you don't need a VM for VHD(X) files. You can just attach/detach them in Disk Management. (Even double-click on them will do, IIRC)

Comment: @TomYan, I will test that asap.